unexpected reversed secondary y axis on dataframe plot
I'm trying to plot a electrical consumption, first in mA with a date, and with secondary axis in W with julian day.
I refered to this matplotlib article, and even if the example works perfectly, I can't figrure where mine differ of it.
Because my secondary y axis is inverted as it's supposed to be.
Here my prog :
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime


path = '[...]TEMPORARY/CR1000_test_intergration/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path , "*.dat"))
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,
                     skiprows=[0,2,3], 
                     header=0, 
                     index_col=0
                     )
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0)
frame=frame.sort_values('TIMESTAMP')
frame.fillna(0)
frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

st_date = pd.to_datetime("2024-05-12 23:30:00", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
en_date = frame.index[-1]


mask = frame.loc[st_date:en_date].index
window1 = frame.loc[(frame.index >= st_date) & (frame.index <= en_date)]

#PLOT   
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,6), dpi=150, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('CUBE CONSO',fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)
ax.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=6))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d | %H:%M')) 
ax.set_ylabel('A')

ax.plot(window1.index,window1['R2_voltage_Avg'], color='r', linewidth=2)

def date2yday(x):
    y = x - mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1))
    return y

def yday2date(x):
    y = x + mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1))
    return y

secax_x = ax.secondary_xaxis(
    'top', functions=(date2yday, yday2date))
secax_x.set_xlabel('julian day [2024]')

def ma_to_w(x):
    return (x * 12.5)

def w_to_ma(x):
    return (12.5 / (x+0.0001)) #avoid divide by 0

secax_y = ax.secondary_yaxis(
    'right', functions=(ma_to_w,w_to_ma))
secax_y.set_ylabel('W')

And here a sample of data (the concatened dataframe) :
TIMESTAMP   RECORD  R1_voltage_Avg  R2_voltage_Avg  out1_voltage_Avg    out2_voltage_Avg
2024-05-13 00:00:00 34155   0.286   0.099   78.56   3.949
2024-05-13 00:01:00 34156   0.797   0.104   20.91   0.057
2024-05-13 00:02:00 34157   0.599   0.091   41.6    0.966
2024-05-13 00:03:00 34158   0.519   0.097   27.76   0.824
2024-05-13 00:04:00 34159   0.814   0.096   27.39   0.455
2024-05-13 00:05:00 34160   0.828   0.101   19.75   0.398
2024-05-13 00:06:00 34161   0.664   0.098   58.36   1.193
2024-05-13 00:07:00 34162   0.081   0.1 49.98   1.023
2024-05-13 00:08:00 34163   0.414   0.098   50.26   0.739
2024-05-13 00:09:00 34164   0.708   0.101   45.97   0.568
2024-05-13 00:10:00 34165   0.698   0.099   82.2    3.552
2024-05-13 00:11:00 34166   0.524   0.101   40.6    -0.54
2024-05-13 00:12:00 34167   0.793   0.093   63.76   3.864
2024-05-13 00:13:00 34168   0.72    0.086   12.76   -0.256
2024-05-13 00:14:00 34169   0.564   0.096   23.44   0.881
2024-05-13 00:15:00 34170   0.67    0.094   30.17   2.33

And finally a plot :


What do you expect the plot to be?

@SergedeGossondeVarennes probably for it to apply the function ma_to_w on the existing y axis and use those values (which should still have it as an ascending axis)

Posted an answer. Check if it is what you expect.

What are you trying to plot? The values you have are voltages, but you label the left y-axis as "A" suggesting you want amps? Whereas it looks like your trying to have power on the hand axis. You are getting the secondary axis inverted as you are specifying an inverse relationship in your functions.

Do not pay attention to the label, I'm using shunt resistor with a conversion factor that give amper by reading millivolt. I'm expecting the right secondary axis is not reversed, as is it now ; it's a decrease scale but it should be increase (Amper to Watt). I'll try the respond given below.

Oh damn it, I just inverted the P=U*I formula (in french) by dividing voltage by ampere instead ampere by voltage. I'm stupid. Thanks for your help.

It is unclear what you are expecting, but here is what I would have done:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

# Sample data
data = {
    'TIMESTAMP': [
        '2024-05-13 00:00:00', '2024-05-13 00:01:00', '2024-05-13 00:02:00', '2024-05-13 00:03:00', '2024-05-13 00:04:00',
        '2024-05-13 00:05:00', '2024-05-13 00:06:00', '2024-05-13 00:07:00', '2024-05-13 00:08:00', '2024-05-13 00:09:00',
        '2024-05-13 00:10:00', '2024-05-13 00:11:00', '2024-05-13 00:12:00', '2024-05-13 00:13:00', '2024-05-13 00:14:00',
        '2024-05-13 00:15:00'
    ],
    'R2_voltage_Avg': [0.099, 0.104, 0.091, 0.097, 0.096, 0.101, 0.098, 0.1, 0.098, 0.101, 0.099, 0.101, 0.093, 0.086, 0.096, 0.094]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
df.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 6), dpi=150, sharex=True)
fig.suptitle('CUBE CONSO', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)

plt.xticks(rotation=30)
ax.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d | %H:%M')) 
ax.set_ylabel('A')

ax.plot(df.index, df['R2_voltage_Avg'], color='r', linewidth=2)

def date2yday(x):
    y = x - mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1))
    return y

def yday2date(x):
    y = x + mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1))
    return y

secax_x = ax.secondary_xaxis('top', functions=(date2yday, yday2date))
secax_x.set_xlabel('Julian day [2024]')

def ma_to_w(x):
    voltage = 12.5  
    return (x / 1000) * voltage  

def w_to_ma(x):
    voltage = 12.5  
    return (x / voltage) * 1000  

secax_y = ax.secondary_yaxis('right', functions=(ma_to_w, w_to_ma))
secax_y.set_ylabel('W')

plt.show()

which gives

